# Dealing with immutability in a GUI-based application

Tags: oop, immutability, observer-pattern

I have a GUI based application (Kotlin) that consists of a list of `Note`s to the left (it shows the note's title) and the selected `Note`'s edition screen to the right.

When the users modify the title in the edition screen, the list item must show the new title.

In a mutable world, I'd do something like this:

```
interface Note {
    fun title(): String
    fun content(): String
    fun setTitle(newTitle: String)
    fun setContent(newTitle: String)
    fun addListener(l: Listener)
}

class NoteListItem(n: Note) : Listener {

    init { 
        n.addListener(this)
    }

    override fun onChange() { //from Listener
        repaint();
    }

    fun repaint() {
       //code
    }

}

class NoteEditionScreen(n: Note) {

    fun onTitleTextChanged(newTitle: String) {
        n.setTitle(newTitle)
    }

    //...

}
```

Inside `Note.setTitle` method, listeners are notified.

Both "screens" have the same instance of `Note`, so changes are propagated.

However, with immutability:

```
interface Note {
    fun title()
    fun content()
    fun title(newTitle: String) : Note
    fun content(newContent: String) : Note
}
```

the method `Note.title(String)` returns a **new instance** of `Note` instead of changing the state.

In that case, how can I "notify" to the `NoteListItem` the title has changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, those two concepts don't go together nicely here.

The essence of the elements on your UI is: they allow for **changes**. The user doesn't know (or care) if the underlying object is immutable or  not. He wants to change that title.

Thus, there are two options for you:

- give up on your Node being immutable
- introduce an abstraction layer that is used by your UI

In other words: you can add a mutable `NodeContainer` that is used for displaying immutable node objects on your UI.

Now you have to balance between having the advantages of keeping your Node class immutable and the disadvantages of adding mutable wrapper thingy around the Node class. But that is your decision; depending on your context.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That way, the `Listener`s are added to the mutable `NoteContainer` instead of to the `Note`, arent' they?

Comment: That is how I would do it.